# Site to site Azure tunnel from on premises network to all vnets on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to have  Site to site Azure tunnel from on premises network to all vnets on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes**, see our [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq).  The longer answer would involve understanding your requirements more.  Depending on the "SKU" you pick for your VPN gateway in Azure, there is a limit to the number of tunnels.  The largest SKU limits at 30 tunnels.  If you need more than 30 S2S tunnels, you may want to look at [Azure Virtual WAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-about).

**Azure Virtual WAN** is a networking service that provides optimized and automated branch-to-branch connectivity through Azure. Virtual WAN lets you connect and configure branch devices to communicate with Azure.